# Fluent Cassandra vs Aquiles?

Tags: c#, .net, api, cassandra, fluentcassandra

I am looking into the nosql databases and i am wondering which is better as an adaptor for the cassandra project. I develop in c#.net and so the site gave me a choice of two(very kind). But i want to know which will help me most and be best performance etc. Has any one used either the fluent cassandra or the aquiles and if so how did you get on?

Any comments appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My personal choice is Aquiles. It's updated more frequently than Fluent Cassandra. It also has connection pooling, strong concurrency and high availability characteristics. It's more mature in my opinion. The author is also using it in a high traffic project.

**EDIT: there is a new .net cassandra client http://code.google.com/p/cassandra-sharp/  and it seems more stable(based on the feedbacks from cassandra sharp  google group)**

Comment: Just wanted to point out that FluentCassandra has connection pooling since day one. https://github.com/managedfusion/fluentcassandra/blob/master/src/Connections/PooledConnectionProvider.cs Also should point out that Aquiles is using some of FluentCassandra's code for the GuidGeneration.

Answer (score 2):

You should NOT use FluentCassanra. FluentCassandra is not yet mature. E.G. it has no documentation. Nowhere!
You get two articles of introduction, which cover the basic parts. But, if you want to do something beside that, you WILL get lost.

Comment: Heh, actually you should say the same about Aquiles. The practical aspect of the documentation is very poor. I found FluentCassandra a lot easier to figure out than Aquiles.

Comment: Actually I take back my previous comment. FluentCassandra has a few problems and limitations I came across. On the surface it seems easy to figure out, but only from the perspective of not understanding hjow Cassandra works. Once you have a basic understanding of Cassandra's data model, Aquiles makes a whole lot more sense and also clearly shows itself to be a lot more mature and full-featured.